# Query that counts different combinations

Tags: sql, algorithm, math

First of all, my apologies for the title of this question, I don't have a better idea for the moment. Make a good suggestion and I will fix the title. (If I have permission to do that, I actually don't know.)

### The situation:

I am having a tough time getting the correct SQL query done. I have a setup where people can place orders, with products etc, and they get discounts in certain circumstances.

Consider the following schema:

```
Product:
  [...]

Price:
  product_id: integer
  description: string
  [...]

Order:
  [...]

OrderItem:
  order_id: integer
  price_id: integer
  amount: integer
```

And consider the following rules:

- There are 9 different products.
- All Products have 2 Prices, one with description *PriceA* and one described *PriceB*.
- All these prices are the same per type for every product. (That is, all PriceA prices are the same, and all PriceB prices are the same.)

### The problem:

For every set of 5 *different* products with *the same* price level (i.e. PriceA vs. PriceB), the total price of the order is lowered with a certain amount. I am trying to write a query that tells me how many times that happens.

### Examples:

**Example 1:**
A user places an order:

- 5 times product1,
- 5 times product2,
- 5 times product3,
- 3 times product4,
- 3 times product5.

All at PriceA, the customer receives 3 times the discount, since there are 3 complete sets of 5

**Example 2:**
A user places an order:

- 5 times product1,
- 5 times product2,
- 5 times product3,
- 5 times product4,
- 2 times product5,
- 2 times product6,
- 2 times product7

All the PriceA price. Now, the customer receives 5 times the discount, since there are 4 sets of 5, two involving product5, two involving product6 and one involving product7.

### The struggle:

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT min(amount) as amount from
    (SELECT oi.amount from `order` o
        inner join orderitem oi on oi.order_id = o.id
        inner join price p on oi.price_id = p.id AND p.description = "PriceA"
        inner join product pr on p.product_id = pr.id
        order by oi.amount desc
        limit 5) as z
    having count(amount) = 5;
```

This beautifully works for Example 1, but in example 2, it will give the wrong result, as it will select the first set of 5 items, and then disregard the

The question is: Is this solvable in SQL? Or would I be better of broadening my selection and doing the math by scripting? (My web application is written in PHP, so I do have room for some server-side mathematics.)

### The solution:

I implemented Neil's solution; it now looks like this:

```
/** @var $oid integer The order ID. */

/* Select all amounts ordered per item, only for a given price title. */
$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT oi.amount as amount FROM orderitems oi
    INNER JOIN orders   o  ON oi.order_id  = o.id AND o.id = $oid
    INNER JOIN prices   p  ON oi.price_id  = p.id AND p.title = '%s'
    INNER JOIN products pr ON p.product_id = pr.id
    ORDER BY oi.amount DESC
SQL;
$discountInfo = array(
    array(
        'price'     => 'PriceA',
        'discounts' => array(
            9 => 49.50, /* Key is 'size of set', value is 'discount'. */
            5 => 23.50
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'price' => 'PriceB',
        'discounts'  => array(
            9 => 22,
            5 => 10,
        ),
    ),
);

foreach($discountInfo as $info)
{
    /* Store all ordered amounts per item in Array. */
    $arr = array();
    $result = $this->dbQuery(sprintf($sql,$info['price']));
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $arr[] = $row['amount'];

    foreach ($info['discounts'] as $am => $di)
    {
        /* For each highest set of $am items, fetch the smallest member. */
        while (count($arr) >= $am)
        {
            /* Add discount for each complete set */
            $discount += $di * $arr[$am - 1];

            /* Substract the amounts from all members of the set */
            for ($i=0; $i<=$am - 1; $i++) $arr[$i] -= $arr[$am - 1];

            /* Remove all elements that are 0 */
            foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) if ($v == 0) unset ($arr[$k]);

            /* Array is messed up now, re-sort and re-index it. */
            rsort($arr);
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: This is a math problem really. If you can find an algorithm that finds the number of sets, writing the SQL will be easy.

Comment: @ypercube +1. You are absolutely right. Mayby I should start figuring out a solution in a more capable environment to define it. Still, I always feel a bit handicapped when using SQL for these things, might have to do with my lack of SQL skills.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this correctly. You want to group the products in the order by the prices. ie. all products that have the same regular price, and discount price, go into one group. Then, for each such group, inside the group, for every 5 product units, you want to use the discount price, instead of the regular price. Did I get that right? In other words, the reason why the products x 2, 2 and 1 of products 5, 6 and 7 was grouped together was because they had the same price, is that about it?

Comment: @LasseVKarlsen, No! I was being ambiguously using the term 'discount'. To clear things up, I replaced 'regular' and 'discount' to 'PriceA' and 'PriceB'. The discount that is substracted is an arbitrary amount, that is always the same, and for me, doesn't have to be in the database or even in the query. (It may just be in the script.) In Example 2, there should be 5 sets: 1-2-3-4-5 x 2; 1-2-3-4-6 x 2; 1-2-3-4-7 x 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it in code: Split the items into two arrays, one for each price level. For each array of products, while there are at least five products in the array:

1. Sort the array in descending order by the number of items of product
2. Add the number of items of the fifth product in the array to the total number of discounts
3. Subtract the number of items of the fifth product in the array from the first five products in the array
4. Delete any zero elements from the array

Comment: I thought of this as well, I just thought it would be lovely to put it all in a SQL query. (Oh well, there's WHILE in SQL... It's around midnight in here, I'll give it a whirl tomorrow...)

Comment: Not getting my hands wet on something like arrays in MySQL. I implemented this solution in PHP. See below in my question.

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret this correctly, you want to divide the count of records, divided by 5, and find the lowest integer (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor)....

Comment: no, that doesn't always work. See his first example with `5,5,5,3,3`. Correct answer: 3. Your algorithm gives 4.

Comment: Good point - but doesn't that mean the question is inconsistent? Why can we allocate discount to example 2, and not example 3?

Comment: No, in example 3 there are more products (7) to choose for the sets (of 5).

Comment: Imagine every product has a different colour. If I understand correctly, he wants to find maximum number of sets of 5 products with **5 different** colours.

Comment: @ypercube Ah yes, 5 _different_ products. (You can substitute 'product.id' for 'color'. :) )